# Why is the result 0x18 instead of 0x12?

Tags: c

The code is as follows:

```
int main() {
// your code goes here
int val = 0x18;
int val1 = val&0xf + ((val>>4)&0xf)*10;
 printf("%d %d\n",val1,val1&0x3f);
return 0;
}
```

I'm caught in a loop or something I can't figure it out. My handcrafted, step by step calculation places the result at 0x12 which is 18D, but I tried 2 compilers the print out was always 0x18.

Why is that?

The last step I calculated was 8+ 10 = 18?

Comment: Did you try debugging? Split the lines and expressions in more parts. Print everything often and early.

Comment: Are you sure the output was `0x18` or `18`?

Comment: What is `b11000 & b11111`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin b11000?

Comment: You see output 18 because you are printing a decimal value in the printf("%d",... ) that is an expected output. if you want to see output 12 then use prinf("%x", ...) format specifier. if you want to prefix output with 0x (0x12) then use printf("0x%x", ...);

Comment: @Miko correct, which is hex `0x18` or decimal `24`. Why do you expect `12`?

Comment: Hint, the conversion specifiers are mnemonics. %decimal, he%xadecimal.

Comment: Though, of course the output from this program is **24** which *is* 0x18, and this question is missing a proper [mcve].

Comment: And it is the operator precedence issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int val1 = (val&0xf) + ((val>>4)&0xf)*10`

add parentheses around `val&0xf`, check c operator precedence for details.

if you want hex format, use `printf("%x", ...)`

---

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Add parenthesis did the trick. This is really strang? "+" is higher prioritized than "&"? Also, I hope this don't sound silly, after you perform operation and calculation on val, the value of val changes, right? No compiler is smart enough to store it in some "temporary location", right?

Comment: @Miko no, `val` does not change, use `printf("%x\n",val);` to check